# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek' - How to fix it?

Tags: python

[AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
How to fix this error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqYjI.png)

Comment: use a debugger. look at the value of `fp`. -- and don't tag things that aren't relevant to the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.